# Memcached: Where to put?

Tags: linux, drupal, memcached

For Drupal Stack, i have 3 Servers:

- Varnish
- Web Server
- Database Server

.. and ***let's say i ONLY have this 3 Servers limitation. No more server***.

Now i have to install `Memcached` but i'm not sure where to install it.
So the `Memcached` for the Drupal Stack:

- Where to put at? (Instead of talking about an another separate box.)

Honestly, as i found `Drupal Memcached Module`, then i though `Memcached` is meant for Application Server where the Drupal is sitting at. So i have put it on the Web/Application Server but it seems the result is even worse then before. So where? At Database Server? Or, on all?

Comment: Add yet another Server for it.

Comment: let's say i ONLY have this 3 Servers limitation. No more server

Answer (score 3):

Your Varnish server is already using a lot of its RAM to store cached pages. Its load should be kept as low as possible to allow it to quickly produce responses to HTTP requests. Caching with Memcache will not reduce its load.

Your Drupal server is already loaded answering requests. Drupal usually consume a lot of RAM. And the main reason to put Varnish on top of it, is to reduce its load. It wont make sense to ask more from this server. Caching with Memcache will not reduce its load.

Your database server is mostly busy with disk I/O for the database request made by Drupal. Its main load is I/O bound and caching with Memcache will reduce its load. Memcached should not add more disk I/O and won't need a lot of CPU. It will only add more network I/O, so unless your database server is overwhelmed with network I/O it should be fine.

So I would put the memcached on the database server.